# Kubernetes: Getting the IP Addresses of Other Pods on the Network

Tags: docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, memcached, google-kubernetes-engine

What's the best way to get the IP addresses of the other kubernetes pods on a local network?

Currently, I'm using the following command and parsing the output: `kubectl describe pods`.

Unfortunately, the command above often takes many seconds to complete (at least 3, and often 30+ seconds) and if a number of requests happen nearly simultaneously, I get 503 style errors. I've built a caching system around this command to cache the IP addresses on the local pod, but when a 10 or so pods wake up and need to create this cache, there is a large delay and often many errors. I feel like I'm doing something wrong. Getting the IP addresses of other pods on a network seems like it should be a straightforward process. So what's the best way to get them?

For added details, I'm using Google's kubernetes system on their container engine. Running a standard Ubuntu image.

---

**Context**: To add context, I'm trying to put together a shared memcached between the pods on the cluster. To do that, they all need to know eachother's IP address. If there's an easier way to link pods/instances for the purposes of memcached, that would also be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For your described use case you should be using services. A headless service would allow you to reference them with `my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`. This assumes you don't need to know individual nodes, only how to reach one of them, as it will round robin between them.

If you do need to have fixed network identities in your cluster attached to the pods you can setup a StatefulSet and reference them with: `app-0.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local`, `app-1.my-svc.my-namespace.svc.cluster.local` and so on.

You should never need to contact specific pod ip's in other ways, specially since they can be rescheduled at any time and have their IPs changed.

For your use case specifically, it might be easier to just use the memcache helm chart, which supports a cluster in a StatefulSet: https://github.com/kubernetes/charts/tree/master/stable/memcached

Comment: Memcache requires knowing all of the servers on the network that are participating in the memcache pool. Not sure this would work.

Comment: Please see my second part of the answer for when you do need to know all the identities in the network using StatefulSets.

Comment: Never had heard of StatefulSets and looks like they're pretty new, Kubernetes is a real moving target!

Answer (score 10):

Have you tried

```
kubectl get pods -o wide
```

This also returns IP addresses of the pods. Since this does not return ALL information `describe` returns, this might be faster.

Comment: I tried this command and I don't think it's much better (maybe marginally). Also, if there are many of these requests (e.g., each process on each pod makes one), you still get the 503 errors. For now, I'm using a custom ip 
filesystem-based cache. Seems strange there isn't a fast and easy way to get all the IPs on the network.